# Python: How to use 'request' object with session scoped fixture

Tags: python-2.7, fixtures

I have a fixture, which is scoped as 'session'. This fixture does some initialization by extracting values from 'request' object.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_context(request):
context_dict = {}
value_for_key = request.param('key')
```

However, when I run the tests, I get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SubRequest' object has no attribute 'param'
```

How do I get the values from request object when the scope is session.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. I realized that the request object is being formed within conftest.py. After making appropriate changes, I am able to access it correctly.

Comment: can you share more details of what you have done to access it correctly??